# Difficulty converting string to date?

Tags: c#

I wrote a program that does work with files like delete and update, store, and search And all customers,But the problem I keep getting the following error when I do an update of the file

**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

[**Project File**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0hmrd9tlrymqmb/CoustomersApp2.rar)

[**Project Video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAqZa38-h_Q&feature=youtu.be)

This error occurs in the Deserialize method:

```
        public Order Deserialize(string str)
    {
        Order order = new Order();
        var strOrder = str.Split(',');
        order.Id = int.Parse(strOrder[0]);

        **order.Date = DateTime.Parse(strOrder[1]);**
        order.Price = int.Parse(strOrder[2]);
        order.Description = strOrder[3];
        order.CustomerId = int.Parse(strOrder[4]);

        return order;
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `strOrder[1]` ?

Comment: You have shown the string in the video, but did you check that strOrder[1] has the intended value? Can you add debug printing there?

Comment: The file is read and the string value example "2/5/2012".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Convert.ToDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130987%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Edit per comment.**

Import `System.Globalization` and try this:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strOrder[1], cultureInfo);
```

Comment: How about the other approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely to do with the culture settings. you need to specify the formats expected by using one of the overloads for the DateTime.ParseExact methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx